# Ambari 1.7.0 cannot register datanodes in CentOS cluster

Tags: linux, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

Here is another question about getting hosts to register.  I am using Ambari 1.7.0 on CentOS 6 machines.  I am trying to install HDP 2.1.

First here is the hosts file I am using.  Note each node has the same hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.200.144 datanode10.localdomain.com
192.168.200.107 datanode01.localdomain.com
192.168.200.143 namenode.localdomain.com
```

Also, I can ping each machine for any machine.
I can SSH without a password from the name node into the other datanodes.
I disabled selinux and iptables on all machines.

I am following the startup procedure listed here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Install+Ambari+1.7.0+from+Public+Repositories. Please note that these install instructions mention nothing about iptables or selinux.  People on the mailing list have told me that I need to disable those items.

Ambari can discover the namenode it is sitting on.  It cannot discover the datanodes.  I get this error from the registration log file:

```
Verifying ambari-agent process status...
Ambari Agent successfully started
Agent PID at: /var/run/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.pid
Agent out at: /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.out
Agent log at: /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.log
("WARNING 2014-12-17 10:43:08,349 NetUtil.py:92 - Server at https://namenode.localdomain.com.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode:8440 is not reachable, sleeping for 10 seconds...
```

---

Why is the namenode being appended to the namenode.localdomain.com URL?  Why is the script considering this a valid 
URL and not throwing an error?

What follows is the full registration log file.

```
==========================
Creating target directory...
==========================

Command start time 2014-12-17 10:43:22

Connection to datanode10.localdomain.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=datanode10.localdomain.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-12-17 10:43:22

==========================
Copying common functions script...
==========================

Command start time 2014-12-17 10:43:22

scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_commons
host=datanode10.localdomain.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-12-17 10:43:23

==========================
Copying OS type check script...
==========================

Command start time 2014-12-17 10:43:23

scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/os_check_type.py
host=datanode10.localdomain.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-12-17 10:43:23

==========================
Running OS type check...
==========================

Command start time 2014-12-17 10:43:23
Cluster primary/cluster OS type is redhat6 and local/current OS type is redhat6

Connection to datanode10.localdomain.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=datanode10.localdomain.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-12-17 10:43:23

==========================
Checking 'sudo' package on remote host...
==========================

Command start time 2014-12-17 10:43:23
sudo-1.8.6p3-15.el6.x86_64

Connection to datanode10.localdomain.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=datanode10.localdomain.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-12-17 10:43:24

==========================
Copying repo file to 'tmp' folder...
==========================

Command start time 2014-12-17 10:43:24

scp /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo
host=datanode10.localdomain.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-12-17 10:43:24

==========================
Moving file to repo dir...
==========================

Command start time 2014-12-17 10:43:24

Connection to datanode10.localdomain.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=datanode10.localdomain.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-12-17 10:43:24

==========================
Copying setup script file...
==========================

Command start time 2014-12-17 10:43:24

scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/setupAgent.py
host=datanode10.localdomain.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-12-17 10:43:24

==========================
Running setup agent script...
==========================

Command start time 2014-12-17 10:43:24
Verifying Python version compatibility...
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.6
Found ambari-agent PID: 3622
Stopping ambari-agent
Removing PID file at /var/run/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.pid
ambari-agent successfully stopped
Restarting ambari-agent
Verifying Python version compatibility...
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.6
ambari-agent is not running. No PID found at /var/run/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.pid
Verifying Python version compatibility...
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.6
Checking for previously running Ambari Agent...
Starting ambari-agent
Verifying ambari-agent process status...
Ambari Agent successfully started
Agent PID at: /var/run/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.pid
Agent out at: /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.out
Agent log at: /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.log
("WARNING 2014-12-17 10:43:08,349 NetUtil.py:92 - Server at https://namenode.localdomain.com.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode:8440 is not reachable, sleeping for 10 seconds...
INFO 2014-12-17 10:43:18,359 NetUtil.py:48 - Connecting to https://namenode.localdomain.com.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode:8440/ca
WARNING 2014-12-17 10:43:18,360 NetUtil.py:71 - Failed to connect to https://namenode.localdomain.com.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode:8440/ca due to [Errno -2] Name or service not known  
WARNING 2014-12-17 10:43:18,360 NetUtil.py:92 - Server at https://namenode.localdomain.com.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode:8440 is not reachable, sleeping for 10 seconds...
INFO 2014-12-17 10:43:28,370 NetUtil.py:48 - Connecting to https://namenode.localdomain.com.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode:8440/ca
WARNING 2014-12-17 10:43:28,370 NetUtil.py:71 - Failed to connect to https://namenode.localdomain.com.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode:8440/ca due to [Errno -2] Name or service not known  
WARNING 2014-12-17 10:43:28,371 NetUtil.py:92 - Server at https://namenode.localdomain.com.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode:8440 is not reachable, sleeping for 10 seconds...
INFO 2014-12-17 10:43:31,082 main.py:83 - loglevel=logging.INFO
INFO 2014-12-17 10:43:31,082 main.py:55 - signal received, exiting.
INFO 2014-12-17 10:43:31,082 ProcessHelper.py:39 - Removing pid file
INFO 2014-12-17 10:43:31,083 ProcessHelper.py:46 - Removing temp files
INFO 2014-12-17 10:43:36,764 main.py:83 - loglevel=logging.INFO
INFO 2014-12-17 10:43:36,764 DataCleaner.py:36 - Data cleanup thread started
INFO 2014-12-17 10:43:36,765 DataCleaner.py:117 - Data cleanup started
INFO 2014-12-17 10:43:36,767 DataCleaner.py:119 - Data cleanup finished
INFO 2014-12-17 10:43:36,801 PingPortListener.py:51 - Ping port listener started on port: 8670
WARNING 2014-12-17 10:43:36,802 main.py:235 - Unable to determine the IP address of the Ambari server 'namenode.localdomain.com.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode'
INFO 2014-12-17 10:43:36,802 NetUtil.py:48 - Connecting to https://namenode.localdomain.com.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode:8440/ca
WARNING 2014-12-17 10:43:36,802 NetUtil.py:71 - Failed to connect to https://namenode.localdomain.com.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode:8440/ca due to [Errno -2] Name or service not known  
WARNING 2014-12-17 10:43:36,802 NetUtil.py:92 - Server at https://namenode.localdomain.com.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode.namenode:8440 is not reachable, sleeping for 10 seconds...
", None)

Connection to datanode10.localdomain.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=datanode10.localdomain.com, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-12-17 10:43:39

Registering with the server...
Registration with the server failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you have specified as the hostname in /etc/ambari-agent/conf/ambari-agent.ini ?
I assume that it is 'namenode.localdomain.com'

Comment: sorry, I know this isn't an answer but when I tried to add a comment to the original question I got a message that I needed I higher reputation.

Comment: I had to go the the other nodes in the cluster and check the ambari-agent.ini files there.  They had the incorrect URL.  They were using namenode.namenode.localdomain.com.